# Error while integrating conversation service sdk(watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk) in Swift

Tags: swift, watson-conversation

I have written swift code for conversation service by importing package in Package.swift:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MySwift",
    dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk.git", majorVersion: 0)
])
```

The code in main.swift is:

```
import ConversationV1 

import Foundation

let username = "707f2a71-1fcb-4db8-a1a8-df831715d5ad"

let password = "tzQs3XMvjsOS"

let version = "2016-07-11" // use today's date for the most recent version

let conversation = Conversation(username: username, password: password, version: version)

let workspaceID = "a5d1decd-225e-4f35-b1ef-c72a672dc6a2"

let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }

var context: Context? // save context to continue conversation

print("calling conversation.message");

conversation.message(withWorkspace: workspaceID, failure: failure) { response in

    print("Response = \(response)")
    context = response.context
}
sleep(10)
```

The above application receives json from conversation service but throws an error while decoding the json. The error is thrown in JSON.swift of RestKit. The error is thrown at point when

```
"dialog_stack" =     (
        root
    );
```

is decoded.

It expects ("root") but gets (root).
The error thrown is :

> unexpectedSubscript(Swift.String) response.result)
>   failure(RestKit.JSON.Error.unexpectedSubscript(Swift.String))

Can anyone help how this can be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback and opening an issue in Github.  For reference, this is related to an older version date being used in the instantiation verses the SDK keeping up with the latest service implementation.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/issues/585

Please let us know if you run into more issue!